# rest-client error 412

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am using ruby and rest-client gem.

I try to communicate with a RESTFUL API.

It's working fine if I use the following:

```
RestClient.post "http://www.restfulapi.com/students/284433/enroll", {:token => token, :param1 => "56303", :param2 => ""}.to_json, :content_type => :json
```

but if I decide to use the active resource style:

```
api = RestClient::Resource.new "http:/www.restfulapi.com"

response = api["/students/284433/enroll"].post  :params => {:token => token, :param1 => "56303", :param2 => ""}
```

I get an error 412 Precondition Failed (RestClient::PreconditionFailed)

I am not sure what exactly is the difference and why one is working and not the other.

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Http status `412 Precondition Failed` means that server doesn't meet correct headers in your request. So it seems that you have to set them manually.

May be this can help.

- rfc2616 – http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
- rest_client docs – http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.7/frames